# Android: Button not showing after dynamic view

Tags: android

I'm trying to dynamically put a bitmap in between a Textview and a Button:

```
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
<LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical" android:text="Button" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/button1">    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

In my Main Activity I create my custom view and add it to the LinearLayout1

```
mView = new myView(this);
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
ll.addView(rView);
```

My problem is, that myView consumes all available space below of it.

What am I missing?

Thnx in advance.

Comment: try adding layout parms for the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set layout Parameter dynamically for your custom View.

```
l1.addView(rView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

similarly try to set left and right position dynamically

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the solution I searched 7h!

Answer (score 1):

You should add the LayoutParams when adding the view:

```
ll.addView(rView, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

In case you want to add it to a specific position you should use: `addView(child, index)`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Dimitris,  I just checked your solution, but my problem remains. As i needed my view (which contains a square bitmap) on width*width size the following code gave me the correct picture:       `ll.addView(rView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ((WindowManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()));`